# Core Location and UITableView performance issues in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, google-maps, ios8, core-location

I have a view controller that contains two views: a **map view** using the Google Maps API and a **UITableView**.

The view controller fetches a list of location objects from Google Maps within a certain radius of a particular location and plots them on the map view as markers and the `UITableView` as `UITableViewCell`s.

User can then tap on a button to transition between these two views.

This works very smoothly in **iOS 7**. However in **iOS 8**, if I request user's location permission by setting up the request permission key-value pair (`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in my case) in my .plist, there is a significant lag when I transition from the map view to the UITableView, and there is also a lag when attempting to scroll the `UITableView`.

As soon as I remove the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in the .plist, it works fine.

I've tried to remove all cell configuration, but the lag exists even loading a `UITableView` with no cells.

Here is my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method after I removed all cell configurations:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
        MyTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[StoreCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];
        }

        return cell;
}
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues? I wonder if this is a bug in iOS 8.

Sorry about the long post, but just wanted to be as thorough as possible.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Turned out that I never stopped the locationManager from updating the current user location so the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method was being called continuously and consuming resources. Once I sent the `stopUpdatingLocation` method to the location manager it fixed the problem